# Vue js add dynamic fields in list with remove and sort not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, vue.js

I am using `Vue js 1.0.25`.

I want to create a `list` using `dynamic textboxes`. The basic idea is on clicking **Add Answer** button, it should create a `dynamic text-box` along with its `index` number like **Ans 1** and with a **Remove** button.

The user can add maximum 5 answers. And also user can `re-order` the answers using **Answer's label as a handler**. I am using `jQuery Sortable` as `Vue directive` for sorting the answers.

It seems working fine, here I have created a JSFiddle for it: [https://jsfiddle.net/devendragohil/6stotpaq/23/](https://jsfiddle.net/devendragohil/6stotpaq/24/)

> But the problem starts when removing an answer after reordering it.
>   Suppose, add any five answers and then reorder them randomly and after
>   that try to remove them one by one, it will behave strange.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know where you issue is, but I think that it is related with `jQuery Sortable` I replicate your example using [vue-sortable](http://sagalbot.github.io/vue-sortable/) an it works pretty well.

Docs are easy, in short you only need to add `v-sortable` to your list container, and anything else should workd as you have it.

**EDIT**

As @g.annunziata mention it on his comment, previous example doesn't work if order and then add a new item.

To solve that we need to update data array as well, add this options on the directive `v-sortable="{onUpdate: onUpdate }"` and add that method on vm

```
onUpdate: function (event) {
   var movingElement = this.answers.splice(event.oldIndex, 1)[0];
   this.answers.splice(event.newIndex, 0, movingElement);
}
```

While I was trying to fix that I get another issue, if I move one element to last position and then add a new item I get this ugly error

[image: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null]

I didn't dig into the real cause of this, but as workaround just add an invisible `div` after element list, something like this.

```
<div class="list-group" v-sortable="{ handle:'.handle', onUpdate: onUpdate }">
  <div class="list-group-item" v-for="answer in answers">
    ...
  </div>
  <div style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

Example has been fixed, please see it at http://jsbin.com/qinofow/edit?html,js,output

Comment: OK. Thanks for the answer. I will check it and will let you know if it works OK for me.

Comment: Example doesn't work. If I change order and after I adds one item, order back to original one.

Comment: Thanks @g.annunziata that was a good catch, please see my edited answer with a fix for that problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you're trying to remove the element, this line here:

```
self.answerList.$remove(answer);
```

This seemed like a good place to simply remove the chosen item from the array using its index and vuejs allows for us to get it when iterating easily.

Take a look at the working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/therealchiko/u9mjt5hd/2/ , I changed the function that removes the box and updated the parameters of the for loop.

Comment: Let me check and let you know.

Comment: No. The same problem is still there. 1) It should not clear any existing answer textbox while adding a new answer. 2) Add five answers, re-arrange them by moving 5th textbox to 2nd position, and then 3rd textbox to 4th position and then start deleting answers 5th then 4th and so on. See it will not work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like when the UI is updated when re-ordering the list, the array is not changed. You should rearrange it when you change the order.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to do it?